# Image inside <a> is not displaying in IE browser?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

Hi i am using this div to open popup using jquery.Popup is working in every browser.But close image of popup is not displaying in IE.

here is div:

```
 <div id="element_to_pop_up2">
 <h3>There will be Delay with shipping this week. </h3>
 <a class="b-close"><a/>
 </div>
```

Here is class that is used to display cross image on popup:

```
.b-close
{

 background: url("x.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline;
 height: 29px;
 left: -18px;
 position: absolute;
 top: -15px;
 width: 25px;
 z-index: 3200;
}
```

x.png image is not displaying in IE.

Comment: Your anchor tag isn't closed.

Answer (score 6):

The `/` is in the wrong place on your anchor tag. It should be `</a>` not `<a/>`

Comment: ohh yes really missed it.Thanks

Comment: @user2397462 But does that fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

combining what everybody before said (Adrift,Kevin and Vector), the tag in not closed properly and the css element should be set to "block".